# Emacs auto saving only in idle state

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to have auto saving only in idle state i.e. when I have not typing. The thing is that a text file can be an encrypted huge one and it's a pain to wait every 5 seconds while it's auto saving. Maybe I missed something very simple but cannot configure it this way using different auto saving scripts, e.g. this one: http://www.litchie.net/programs/real-auto-save.el

Comment: This question isn't off topic, it is about "software tools commonly used by programmers", and can only be solved by writing elisp code to set specific variables that control the auto-save behaviour.

Comment: And to answer the question, I think you just need to set auto-save-interval to 0. And maybe reduce auto-save-timeout, so you don't need to wait for 30 seconds of idle time before the auto-save happens.

Comment: Don't think it's off topic as well, since it's required some elisp code to be solved. Thanks JSON, your solution prtly works but it stores not to the current buffer filename. I've found the code which works fine, though: http://0xcc.net/misc/auto-save/auto-save-buffers.el It does exactly what is needed with the following setup: 
(require 'auto-save-buffers)
(run-with-idle-timer 30 t 'auto-save-buffers)